# create an a link html and perform an action with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery that performs an action when you click on `a.data`. The problem is that when I create several `a.data` with another function, it does not perform the action.

I do not understand why the new `a.data` do not work?

This creates new `a.data` in `divdata`

```
var data_html  = '<a class="data" href="#" value="'data.id'">' + ref.info + '</a>';
$(data_html).prependTo( $('#divdata') );
```

This takes the action to the corresponding `a.data`

```
$('a.data').click( function (){
    $(this).attr('href');
    var idvalue = $(this).attr('value');
    idvalue *= 1;
    // aqui realizo  la acción
    console.log(idvalue);
 });
```

Comment: It'd be awesome if you wrote a jsfiddle demonstrating this.

Comment: It's hard to be sure of what the question is but the answer would probably be to use `$('#divdata').on('a.data','click', function (){`

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting click trigger after you generate the document?

Comment: @dystroy you missed a `.` in front of `.on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/on/ Your binding method only binds to the existing elements. You need to bind to the parent element using on for subsequent elements to be bound.

```
$("#divdata").on("click", "a.data", function(){
  // event stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to delegate the event, like this:

```
$('#divdata').on('click', 'a.data', function (){
    $(this).attr('href');
    var idvalue = $(this).attr('value');
    idvalue *= 1;
    // aqui realizo  la acción
    console.log(idvalue);
 });
```